# How to avoid use touch the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want the user scroll the UITableView, but not to tap the UITableView, how can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you looking to prevent all the cells from responding to being tapped?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is not implement the  didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: You will also need to remove the highlight on the UITableViewCells by setting it's selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to code the delegate function

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (YouWantToAllowTouch)
        return indexPath;
    else
        return nil;
```

}